# Safely delete a generic file with the Windows API

Tags: winapi, delete-file

Is it possible in Windows to irreversibly delete/overwrite the contents of a file, regardless of the storage medium (i.e. without raw I/O access to the drive), as long as write access is granted?

Answer (score 2):

No, at least not in general.

With Windows Vista Microsoft introduced the so-called "Volume Shadow Copies". Due to this, Windows won't necessarily overwrite existing data, even if you indeed tell it to overwrite an existing file with new content (as long as shadow copies are enabled). It's still possible the old version of the file will continue to exist hidden on the drive (and accessible through the file properties window in Explorer), unless there isn't enough disk space to continue doing so.

More Information can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and there's even an API to access this feature, but I guess it's limited to actually write/create new copies only, rather than removing them.

Comment: There's also an issue with flash drives or SSDs, since they do wear leveling and will probably write the new content to physically different locations from the original content.